# TP Link AV500 ethernet connections

Tags: ethernet

The instructions supplied with TPlink AV500 do mention that there are 2 ethernet connections on the power extender but no where does it say whether they can be used for 2 computers, not necessarily at the same time. Does anyone know for sure? I prefer to use an ethernet connection as it's faster and more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

#### No where does it say whether they can be used for 2 computers

> Multiple Ethernet ports to connect the TVs, game consoles, or PCs to the internet **at the same time.**

...

> Connect the Ethernet ports to your wired devices, such as a computer, a router 
>   or a game console, via Ethernet cables

Source [User Guide](http://static.tp-link.com/TL-WPA4220(AU)_V2_User_Guide_1481600446549q.pdf)